# Javadoc validator for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there any way I can check if every javadoc to every method in my entire project is valid meaning it has all the @params and @return necessary according to the method signatures?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in inspection "Declaration has Javadoc problems" checks that. You can run this on your entire project using Analyze | Run Inspection by Name...